# How to return NULL historical records prior to a certain date in My SQL

Tags: mysql

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gXbc.png)

For the tables above I am trying to answer the following question: 
 For each customer_id who made an order on January 1, 2015, what was their historical (prior to January 1, 2015) first and last order dates?

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS first_date, MAX(order_date) AS last_date
FROM Orders
WHERE order_date < '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and customer_id in (SELECT DISTINCT(customer_id) FROM Orders
WHERE order_date between '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and '2015-01-01 23:59:59')
GROUP BY customer_id
```

This however does not return historical records for customers that made no orders prior to Jan 1 2015. I'd like to return those records as well with something like "Not Found" in the date fields. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use dummy dates in a sub query
Given this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS O;
CREATE TABLE O (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, CUSTOMERID INT, DT DATE);
INSERT INTO O (CUSTOMERID, DT) VALUES
(1,'2015-01-01'),(1,'2014-01-01'),(1,'2014-02-01'),
(2,'2015-01-01'),
(3,'2016-01-01');
```

This

```
select customerid,
         if(MinOrdersBefore2015 = '2050-01-01','null',MinOrdersBefore2015) as MinOrdersBefore2015,
         if(MaxOrdersBefore2015 = '2000-01-01','null',maxOrdersBefore2015) as MaxOrdersBefore2015
from
(
SELECT CUSTOMERID,
         min(CASE WHEN DT < STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d') THEN DT ELSE '2050-01-01' end) MinOrdersBefore2015,
         mAX(CASE WHEN DT < STR_TO_DATE('2015-01-01','%Y-%m-%d') THEN DT ELSE '2000-01-01' end) MaxOrdersBefore2015
FROM   O
group by customerid having  sum(case when dt = '2015-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
) s
```

Results in

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| customerid | MinOrdersBefore2015 | MaxOrdersBefore2015 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1 | 2014-01-01          | 2014-02-01          |
|          2 | null                | null                |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```